# Array loading with doubles in C

Tags: c, arrays, double, loading

I am trying to load a 3x8 array of doubles but my code keeps outputting 0.00 for all of the values.  The code should be outputting the array (same as the input) under the Read#1 Read#2 Read#3 lines, with the average under average.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double getAvg(double num1, double num2, double num3);

int main()
{
        int numJ,month,day,year,i,j;
        double arr[3][8];

        scanf("%d %d %d %d",&numJ,&month,&day,&year);

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
              scanf("%f %f %f",&arr[i][0], &arr[i][1], &arr[i][2]);
        }

        printf("\nJob %d Date: %d/%d/%d",numJ,month,day,year);
        printf("\n\nLocation Read#1 Read#2 Read#3 Average");
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
              printf("\n       %d   %.2f   %.2f   %.2f   %.2f",j+1,arr[j][0],arr[j]  [1],arr[j][2],getAvg(arr[j][0],arr[j][1],arr[j][2]));            
        }

        return 0;
}

double getAvg(double num1, double num2, double num3)
{
        double avg = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3;
        return avg;
}
```

Input example:

```
157932   09 01 2013
0.00 0.00 0.00
0.36 0.27 0.23
0.18 0.16 0.26
0.27 0.00 0.34
0.24 0.00 0.31
0.16 0.33 0.36
0.29 0.36 0.00
0.21 0.36 0.00
```

Comment: Not sure it effects the point of your question at this point, but you are not passing `GetAvg()` anywhere.  Also, it looks as if some of your code has been cut off? `printf("\n       %d   %.2f   %.2f   %.2f   %.2f",j+1,arr[0][j],arr[$`

Comment: your code does not make sense. Please check if you have copied correctly. This line looks incomplete.
printf("\n       %d   %.2f   %.2f   .....

Comment: scanf("%f %f %f" should be scanf("%lf %lf %lf"

Comment: ok I reposted the code

Comment: the %lf fixed it, thanks to all

Comment: You should parse your input using `fgets` and robust whitespace handling ... When you provide the wrong amount of whitespace to `scanf`, it fails to retrieve the numbers (which is occurring at the very beginning because there are 3 spaces between your `numJ` and your `month` field).

Comment: Also, you need to use "%lf" for reading in a double., you have "%f".  sprintf will let you get away with that, scanf will not.